# Band of thieves - escape locations if some of them are compromised

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, puzzle

I am currently reading a book in which we follow a band of 5 thieves which are about to do something big and some of them might be captured.

They would like to meet up afterwards but have to expect that some of their previously shared locations are compromised by being pried out of the caught ones of their group. All of them would know which ones of them have been caught.

While the book certainly does not solve this problem mathematically how could the band of thieves make sure the locations are distributed in a way that they can not be compromised by losing some of their group. Things that don't work:

Have each thief only know 2 locations like here:

[image: thieves sharing 2 locations each]

In this case if thieves A, C and E would be caught thieves B and D would not have a shared set of locations to check anymore and could not meet up.

What about greater groups of thieves? How many locations would they have to share beforehand?

Comment: What problem is it you are trying to solve?  As you say, with the stated example, it may be the case that two free thieves can not meet.  So...what's special, if anything, about that solution?

Comment: If we trust that the thieves know who is free, then $\binom n2$ suffices, giving a separate location to each pair.  If $A,B,C$ are free then $A,B$ meet at their spot, and then go to the spot known to $B,C$, say.  Or is this not what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that $\binom n2$ should suffice and is minimal, giving a distinct location to every pair.

Clearly you need at least that many, as it is possible that any designated pair of thieves might be the only ones standing.

To see that this number suffices, suppose a larger group, $A_1,\cdots, A_k$, of thieves survives.  Then $A_1, A_2$ meet at their private spot, from which they go off to meet $A_3$ at the secret spot known only to $A_2,A_3$ (say) and so on.

To add more detail:  the $n$ thieves must agree on an ordering in advance.  Then, of course, every subset is ordered so the thieves all know who is $A_1$ who is $A_2$ and so on.  Then, to fix a system, $A_1,A_2$ agree (in advance) to meet in their spot.  And for $i>1$ $A_i$ goes to wait in the spot known to him and to $A_{i-1}$.

Should say:  the rules are not entirely clear to me.

Comment: +1 The rules are indeed unclear, but "in real life" I see no reason why this cannot be implemented. And this is much better than $2^n-n-1$.

Comment: This only works if adjacent thieves are free by chance. In the given example where from a list of thieves A,B,C,D,E the thieves A, C, E are compromised leaving only B, D who are not adjacent are free there would be no way for B, D to have a shared location. Unless I am missing something? I think the Matthews answer is correct.

Comment: @Locke   No...Any subset works.  the thieves just agree on an ordering in advance, so they know who is $A_1$ who is $A_2$ etc.  If $A_1,\cdots, A_k$ are the last thieves standing, then $A_1$ goes to place $P_{1,2}$ and for $i>1$ $A_i$ goes to place $P_{i-1,i}$.  This is extremely easy to implement for any number and any subset.

Comment: Ooh now I understand. I totally misunderstood. You are right this would work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given $n$ thieves, $T_1$ through $T_n$, they would need to know a separate hideout for each possible arrangement of thieves being caught or not caught, except they wouldn't need to worry about a hideout if they were all caught.  For instance, if $\{T_2, T_4,T_5\}$ were caught, they would need a special hideout that everyone else knew about (so they could get there) and none of those three thieves knew about (so they couldn't give that information out).

So, in general, that is a total of $2^n-1$ different hideouts.  In your example with just five thieves, they would need $31$ different places to hide.

(To make things a little simpler, the cases where there was just one successful thief wouldn't be shared among the group obviously, so that would lead to $n$ fewer cases.)

Answer (score 0):

Let each subset of size $2$ or more have a secret location known only to that subset.  For $n$ thieves, this requires $2^n-n-1$ locations.